# Excel VBA Worksheet_Change is slow first, then faster

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this really odd problem, when initializing my Worksheet_Change event the first time, there is about a 2 second pause before the event "fires". After the initial time, the event gets much faster. Anyone have this experience before?

Code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox "Firing"
    Debug.Print "1"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Debug.Print "2"
    If Sheets("Drop Downs").Cells(6, 2) = "1" Then
        If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "3"
            Call SummarySheetUpdater
            Debug.Print "4"
        End If
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

On the first run, the msgbox appears after about 2 seconds, afterwords it appears almost immediately.

Also, the Debug.Print flags I placed within the sub all display in quick succession so I know its something odd with the event initialization.

I understand this is a bit of a "Aim at the target blindfolded" request, I apologize.

Comment: So if the delay is before the first line of code runs then posting the code here is of no value. More information about the spreadsheet would be required to help you. Do you have any other events that could be running, like things from workbook open? Is it a large workbook with lot's of things going on?

Comment: Auto_Open does have a subroutine it runs, but the subroutine is fairly short and finishes quickly. The workbook is fairly complex (3-4000 lines of code and 486kb in .xlsb format). If it helps, the workbook produces a new workbook with only a fraction of the modules/userforms copied over, this second workbook is where I am seeing the delay.

Comment: So it would make more sense to look at the stuff in the first work book and the auto open. As I said before, the code you posted here is not where the problem is.